# SharePoint List (with Choice/Checkboxes column) to Google Chart

Tags: list, google-chart

i am using the following code (Naveen Kaliyaperumaal) helped me with it, to create a pie chart from a SharePoint list choice (checkboxes = multiple answers possible) column.
But the charts are still not correct. Every chart created is just equally distributed with 1 per status.

```
<div id="piechart" style="width:900px;height:500px;"></div>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
        <script type="text/javaScript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var tempArray = [];
                var chartObj = [['status', 'Number']];

                AjaxCall(_spPageContextInfo.webabsoluteurl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('IncidentsReports')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Status'", function (data) {
                    $.each(data.d.results[0].Choices.results, function (index, value) {
                        if (0 > tempArray.indexOf(value)) {
                            tempArray.push(value);
                            chartObj.push([value, 1])
                        } else {
                            chartObj[tempArray.indexOf(value) + 1][1] += 1;
                        }
                    });
                    google.charts.load('current', {
                        'packages': ['corechart']
                    });
                    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
                        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartObj);
                        var options = {
                            title: 'test title',
                            is3D: 'true'
                        };
                        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
                        chart.draw(data, options);
                    });
                });
            });
            function AjaxCall(url, success) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    },
                    success: success,
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                        alert('Something Went Wrong');
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

EDIT:
i changed the $.each part to this

```
$.each(data.d.results, function (index, row) {
                    // each row
                        $.each(row.Choices.results, function (index2, choice) {
                        // each choice of single row
                         if (0 > tempArray.indexOf(choice)) {
                            tempArray.push(choice);
                            chartObj.push([choice, 1])
                        } else {
                            chartObj[tempArray.indexOf(choice) + 1][1] += 1;
                        }
                        });
                    });
```

But i still get the same result...

the list looks like:
[image: list screenshot]

and the chart:
[image: chart]

which is obviously not correct.

[image: console data]

Second console log:

[image: console2]

Now the final code looks like:

```
            <div id="piechart" style="width:900px;height:500px;"></div>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
        <script type="text/javaScript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var tempArray = [];
                var chartObj = [['Orbit', 'Number']];

                AjaxCall(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('test list2')/items", function (data) {

var countOrbit = {};

data.d.results.forEach(function(row) {
    // each row
    row.Orbit.results.forEach(function(choiceOrbit) {
        // each choice of Orbit of single row
        if (countOrbit.hasOwnProperty(choiceOrbit)) {
            countOrbit[choiceOrbit] += 1;
        } else {
            countOrbit[choiceOrbit] = 1;
        }
    });
});


google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {

    var rowsOrbit = [];
    for (var property in countOrbit) {
        if (countOrbit.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            rowsOrbit.push([property, countOrbit[property]]);
        }
    }


    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Type');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
    data.addRows(rowsOrbit);
    var options = {
        title: 'Orbit',
        is3D: 'true'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
});


            });
            });
            function AjaxCall(url, success) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    },
                    success: success,
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                        alert('Something Went Wrong');
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: I would mark it as solved and i would open a new question, well explained because even with the edit i am not pretty sure about what you want to do. Glad that it worked btw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you put the response if the data is not private? or at least some elements of it? or with the data changed?

When you do: `$.each(data.d.results[0].Choices.results ....` you are iterating **only the list first row choices results.**

**EDIT:** The ajax call was incorrect, you should make the request. I also edited the code, now should work:
endpoint 
`/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('IncidentsReports')/items` --> try: `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('IncidentsReports')/items?$select=Orbit` to get only Orbit Column.

```
    var countData = {};
    console.log(data.d.results);

    data.d.results.forEach(function(row) {
        // each row
        row.Orbit.results.forEach(function(choice) {
            // each choice of single row
            // not sure if is choice the property...
            console.log(choice);
            if (countData.hasOwnProperty(choice)) {
                countData[choice] += 1;
            } else {
                countData[choice] = 1;
            }
        });
    });


    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {

        var rows = [];
        for (var property in countData) {
            if (countData.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                rows.push([property, countData[property]]);
            }
        }


        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Type');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
        data.addRows(rows);
        var options = {
            title: 'test title',
            is3D: 'true'
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
```

Comment: the response is in the picture below the code

Comment: i tried your code, but it isnt working :(

Comment: But there is only the picture, not the data itself...

Comment: check my edit in the main post

Comment: Debug the created data into the second $.each. Put a console.log to see the data. I think that part isnt correct. if i have time later i will try to put an example. the json data can you put it also?

Comment: stupid question, but how do i do that?

Comment: before ```var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartObj);``` you can put ```console.log(chartObj);``` and you will see the data before converting it. To see the data, in chrome for example, press f12 and go to console tab. then load the page/ chart and you will see the data structure. I would debug into the foreach because it seems to be failing. Maybe later i can fix

Comment: I edited now try ..

Comment: if i change e.g. "else {countData[choice] = 5;" then all elements in the pie chart are 5. so its always going to the else condition.

Comment: Change the if ```if (countData.hasOwnProperty(choice)) {``` if it doesnt work show the json response of the ajax call

Comment: still doesnt work. how do i show the json response of the ajax call?

Comment: ```console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d.results));``` to be able to paste here easily. If you wanna debug with chrome console you can: ```console.log(data.d.results);``` and you can inspect the object into google Chrome console (you can also with other browsers, but in my case i prefer Chrome). Put it before the first $.each

Comment: I edited again this should work....

Comment: theres still the exact same issue :(

Comment: And what is in rows? ```console.log(rows);``` before: ```var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();```

Comment: see edit........

Comment: I think you have only one item result in the ajax call, could you put the same screenshot log with ```console.log(data.d.results);``` before the first forEach, and ```console.log("rowEach");``` into the first forEach? You have this filter in the query: ```$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Status'``` is that correct? could be responding you only one item? (try to remove it after the debugging to see if the result changes, even if you need it later)

Comment: ok it did that........ in the code i use not it is changed to "Orbit" instead of "Status"

Comment: how many elements has this array? ```https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfbiA.png``` (first child, i can see only the first one -> item 0) It seems the length is just one... thats why the data is all the same

Comment: yes thats right. i dont know whats wrong with the code...

Comment: What you tried, did yuo remove the $filter? what does the $filter do here?

Comment: it selects the orbit column. when i remove it nothing is working anymore.

Comment: Could you paste the result of: ```/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('IncidentsReports')```? with no filter?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Object.success (Statistics.aspx:624)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: Sorry, ```/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('IncidentsReports')/items``` is the call.

Comment: no problem. but i get a similar error with this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
    at Statistics.aspx:627
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (Statistics.aspx:624)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: by the way thanks for taking all this time and helping me with this!

Comment: Dont worry, put the response data ```console.log(JSON.stringify(data));``` before the first each

Comment: <Default>GEO</Default><CHOICES><CHOICE>GEO</CHOICE><CHOICE>HEO</CHOICE><CHOICE>LEO</CHOICE><CHOICE>SSO</CHOICE><CHOICE>POL</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>","Scope":".../Lists/test list2","Sealed":false,"Sortable":false,"StaticName":"Orbit","Title":"Orbit","FieldTypeKind":15,"TypeAsString":"MultiChoice","TypeDisplayName":"Choice","TypeShortDescription":"Choice (menu to choose from)","ValidationFormula":null,"ValidationMessage":null,"FillInChoice":false,"Mappings":null,"Choices":{"__metadata":{"type":"Collection(Edm.String)"},"results":["GEO","HEO","LEO","SSO","POL"]}}]}}

Comment: Paste it into the first item, complete if you can because i see not ```{``` opening..

Comment: as string and not as screenshot you can? to format it... :p

Comment: Wich is the call you made? is the field call, not the list call. You have to do: ```/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('IncidentsReports')/items``` and paste that answer, it will fail the .each but i need to know column names. Paste the answer of ```/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('IncidentsReports')/items```.

The call you are doing is to take a column itself, not that column from the list

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84031/discussion-on-answer-by-mikel-sharepoint-list-with-choice-checkboxes-column-to).

Comment: Thanks! So this is working now. I edited my post to the full code I have now. Do you know how to modify the code in order to have multiple charts of multiple rows?

Answer (score 1):

[Amrein Engineering offers a free Google Web Part if you are interested.](http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5749)

Comment: thx, but i cant install anything on the server

Comment: No worries.  Maybe it will help out someone else who stumbles upon your question.  =)